# Ámbito de variables fuera del foreach en PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código en mi controlador de Laravel:

```
public function show(){
    $user=User::where("id",Auth()->id())->first();
    $vendedores1=User::where("sponsor",Auth()->id())->get();
    $amount1=User::where("sponsor",Auth()->id())->count();
    $amount2=0;
    $amount3=0;
    $vendedores2;
    $vendedores3;
    foreach ($vendedores1 as $vendedor1) {
        $vendedores2=User::where("sponsor",$vendedor1->id)->get();
        $amount2=+User::where("sponsor",$vendedor1->id)->count();
            foreach ($vendedores2 as $vendedor2) {
                $vendedores3=User::where("sponsor",$vendedor2->id)->get();
                $amount3=+User::where("sponsor",$vendedor2->id)->count();
            }
    }
    $cantidad=$amount1+$amount2+$amount3;
    return view("/fuerzadeventa",compact("user","vendedores1","vendedores2","vendedores3","amount1","amount2","amount3","cantidad"));
}
```

Cuando pongo el `dd($vendedores2)` dentro del scope del `foreach`, éste tiene contenido, pero al poner el mismo `dd()` fuera del `foreach` (después de éste), me arroja un arreglo vacío.

**`dd($vendedores2)` dentro del `foreach`:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`dd($vendedores2)` fuera del `foreach`:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `dd($vendedores2)` tras el `foreach` no te arroja el mismo resultado que el último `dd($vendedores2)` de dentro?

Comment: Sí, estoy seguro, me parece muy extraño en realidad.

Comment: Agregué imágenes de lo que me lanza el dd() dentro y fuera del scope

Comment: Tendría que ver la implementación de la clase `User`. Sólo se me ocurre que estés guardando resultados o algo en variables estáticas y consiguientes llamadas a `User::where` estén modificando su valor.

Comment: Cual sería la forma correcta para que los resultados se vayan sumando a una variable?

Comment: ¿`$vendedores2` qué tiene que ver con sumar? Veo que sumas otras variables, pero no esa.

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a cambiar la línea a `$vendedores2 = clone User::where("sponsor",$vendedor1->id)->get();`? Con eso descartaríamos una mala implementación de `User` que reutilizara el objeto de tipo `Collection`.

Comment: O sea, en realidad $vendedores2 es una lista de vendedores que estoy usando, cada vendedor tiene un atributo que es "sponsor", o patrocinador, y quiero crear un "árbol genealógico" de vendedores, para crear equipos de venta. Lo que se suma es el count() de la cantidad de vendedores que hay en cada nivel, son 3 niveles.

Comment: Con clone sigue igual, el mismo problema con el scope, idéntico output

Comment: ¿Entonces para qué necesitas tener el valor de `$vendedores2` fuera del foreach?

Comment: Porque cuando retorno a la vista el valor de $vendedores2, me llega un arreglo vacío, y deseo mostrar la lista total de vendedores en cada nivel.

Comment: Ummm, espera.. el problema quizá lo tengas en otro sitio.. lo que estás haciendo no es sumar, es asignar forzando signo positivo. `$amount2=+User::where("sponsor",$vendedor1->id)->count();` debería ser: `$amount2 += User::where("sponsor",$vendedor1->id)->count();`. Cambia de orden el `=+` por `+=` en todos sitios.

Comment: No es eso, ya eliminé esas líneas de código y sigo teniendo el mismo problema con el scope. De todas formas cambié el orden de los signos y me lanzó un error de variable indefinida: "Undefined variable: amount2"

Comment: No es posible que te lance ese error porque la defines un poco más arriba en `$amount2=0;`... por cierto, ¿podrías usar [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) para facilitar la lectura de tu código?

Comment: Lo sé, estoy empezando a odiar laravel...

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con Laravel, debe ser otra cosa. Me gustaría usar el chat para poder comunicarme contigo mejor, pero aún no tienes reputación suficiente. ¿Tienes teamviewer u otra herramienta para compartir tu escritorio y ver yo mismo qué está pasando?

Comment: hice un var_dump y me dice que la variable está protegida. Dice object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1815 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código hay que cambiar o mejorar lo siguiente:

- Existen algunas consultas repetidas que pueden unirse en una o eliminarse (un `get()` seguido de un `count()` de la misma consulta).
- Estás usando `=+` en vez de `+=` para sumar datos.
- El contenido de las variables `$vendedores2` y `$vendedores3` contendrá el valor que tuvieron durante la última iteración y no el agregado.

Tu código podría quedar tal que así:

```
<?php
public function show()
{
    $user = User::where("id",Auth()->id())->first();
    /* En vez de usar colecciones usaremos matrices */
    $vendedores1 = User::where(
      'sponsor',
      Auth()->id()
    )->get()->all();
    $vendedores2 = [];
    $vendedores3 = [];
    foreach ($vendedores1 as $vendedor1) {
        $vendedores = User::where(
          'sponsor',
          $vendedor1->id
        )->get()->all();
        foreach ($vendedores as $vendedor) {
            /* Agregamos sin repetición al vendedor */
            $vendedores2[$vendedor->id] = $vendedor;
            $subvendedores = User::where(
              'sponsor',
              $vendedor->id
            )->get()->all();
            foreach($subvendedores as $subvendedor) {
                $vendedores3[$subvendedor->id] = $subvendedor;
            }
        }
    }
    /* En vez de repetir la consulta User::where("sponsor",Auth()->id())->get()
      usamos count con tu resultado */
    $amount1 = count($vendedores1);
    /* Lo mismo con el resto, no hace falta ir sumando porque a estas alturas
       tendremos el total */
    $amount2 = count($vendedores2);
    $amount3 = count($vendedores3);
    $cantidad = $amount1 + $amount2 + $amount3;
    return view(
      "/fuerzadeventa",
      compact(
        "user",
        "vendedores1",
        "vendedores2",
        "vendedores3",
        "amount1",
        "amount2",
        "amount3",
        "cantidad"
      )
    );
}
```